# Namespace not marked type-only declare - Babel/Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, babeljs, create-react-app

I have created app via 
npx create-react-app --typescript

And I wanted to use some autogenerated code with namespaces due to that babel throw error

What I tried:

1. Ejected the project
2. Updated babel/core to 7.7 https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8244#issuecomment-507037823
3. Installed and configured https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-transform-typescript.html

```
    {
      "name": "frontend2",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.7.2",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript": "^7.7.2",
        "@svgr/webpack": "4.3.2",
        "@types/jest": "24.0.22",
        "@types/node": "12.12.7",
        "@types/react": "16.9.11",
        "@types/react-dom": "16.9.4",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.2.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.2.0",
        "babel-eslint": "10.0.3",
        "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
        "babel-loader": "8.0.6",
        "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.4",
        "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.0.2",
        "camelcase": "^5.2.0",
        "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.2.0",
        "css-loader": "2.1.1",
        "dotenv": "6.2.0",
        "dotenv-expand": "5.1.0",
        "eslint": "^6.1.0",
        "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.0.2",
        "eslint-loader": "3.0.2",
        "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "3.13.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.18.2",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "7.14.3",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.6.1",
        "file-loader": "3.0.1",
        "fs-extra": "7.0.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.5",
        "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
        "is-wsl": "^1.1.0",
        "jest": "24.9.0",
        "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen": "0.1.0",
        "jest-resolve": "24.9.0",
        "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.4.0",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.8.0",
        "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.3",
        "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.5.0",
        "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
        "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
        "postcss-normalize": "7.0.1",
        "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
        "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
        "react": "^16.11.0",
        "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.4",
        "react-dev-utils": "^9.1.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
        "resolve": "1.12.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "3.1.0",
        "sass-loader": "7.2.0",
        "semver": "6.3.0",
        "style-loader": "1.0.0",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.4.1",
        "ts-pnp": "1.1.4",
        "typescript": "3.7.2",
        "url-loader": "2.1.0",
        "webpack": "4.41.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "3.2.1",
        "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.1.1",
        "workbox-webpack-plugin": "4.3.1"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node scripts/start.js",
        "build": "node scripts/build.js",
        "test": "node scripts/test.js"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      },
      "devDependencies": {},
      "jest": {
        "roots": [
          "<rootDir>/src"
        ],
        "collectCoverageFrom": [
          "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
          "!src/**/*.d.ts"
        ],
        "setupFiles": [
          "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
        ],
        "setupFilesAfterEnv": [],
        "testMatch": [
          "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
          "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
        ],
        "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen",
        "transform": {
          "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
          "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
          "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
        },
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
          "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$",
          "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
        ],
        "modulePaths": [],
        "moduleNameMapper": {
          "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
          "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
        },
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
          "web.js",
          "js",
          "web.ts",
          "ts",
          "web.tsx",
          "tsx",
          "json",
          "web.jsx",
          "jsx",
          "node"
        ],
        "watchPlugins": [
          "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
          "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
        ]
      },
      "babel": {
        "presets": [
          "react-app"
        ],
        "plugins": [
          [
            "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript",
            {
              "allowNamespaces": true
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
```

But still I'm getting below error

```
./src/api/api.ts
SyntaxError: /home/owozniak/IdeaProjects/self-estem/src/main/java/org/owozniak/selfestem/frontend2/src/api/api.ts: Namespace not marked type-only declare. Non-declarative namespaces are only supported experimentally in Babel. To enable and review caveats see: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-typescript
  17 | }
  18 | 
> 19 | export namespace org.owozniak.selfestem.common.models {
     |                  ^^^
  20 | 
  21 |     export interface ProjectApi {
  22 |         readonly id: number;
```

Comment: Well, the error is fairly clear, Babel doesn't support namespaces that contain  _values_, only _types_. While TypeScript itself supports this just fine, your use of namespaces looks confused to say the least. A namespace as qualified as `org.owozniak.selfestem.common.models` doesn't make sense unless you are writing global scripts instead of using modules, and you are using modules. Therefore, if you write code that is more idiomatic when using modules, the issue won't apply to you.

Comment: Ok, how I can resolve it because it is autogenerated code?

Comment: No idea, there's insufficient information provided here for anyone to even consider how to resolve it unless they're intimately familiar with the tool chain that's generating it

Answer (score 6):

In my case I didn't have to eject the settings. I used the packages [react-app-rewired](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired) with the [cutomize-cra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/customize-cra).

1. I created the *config-overrides.js* to overrides the config about **cra** (create-react-app)

   ```
    /* config-overrides.js */
    const { override, useBabelRc } = require('customize-cra');

    module.exports = override(useBabelRc());
   ```
2. And i create the *.babelrc* because the jest config has a file *babelTransform.js* an in this file already has a property **usebabelrc: true** then you only needs add to run on project build and startup.

   ```
    /* .babelrc */
    {
        "plugins": [
            ["@babel/plugin-transform-typescript", { "allowNamespaces": true }]
        ]
    }
   ```

I don’t know if you use the react-app-rewired but if you no use, you need to follow some steps [this steps](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired/) to config

Comment: You're a life saver! No where on the internet could I find a proper solution, not even in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Babel will allow `export declare namespace` syntax.
Mark type-only `namespace`s with `declare`.

The regular `allowNamespaces` right into `.babelrc` would not work with `create-react-app`.
You have to `eject` configs or to use [rescripts](https://github.com/harrysolovay/rescripts) to override those without ejecting.

**Note:** `export namespace` is available with standard tsc compiler,
so if you ejected configs you could use it instead of babel.

---

@seeAlso: [@babel/plugin-transform-typescript — Impartial Namespace Support](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-typescript#impartial-namespace-support)

> Type-only `namespace`s should be marked with `declare` and will subsequently be safely removed.
>
> `namespace`s not marked with `declare` are experimental and disabled by default. Not enabling will result in an error: "Namespace not marked type-only `declare`. Non-declarative namespaces are only supported experimentally in Babel."
>
> **Workaround:** Enable the `allowNamespaces` option.

Answer (score 3):

There's a nice tool to avoid the error thrown: https://github.com/harrysolovay/rescripts

How to:

1. Install rescripts

> npm i -D @rescripts/cli

2. In package.json, replace "react-scripts" with "rescripts":

> ```
> "scripts": {
>      "start": "rescripts start",
>      "build": "rescripts build",
>      "test": "rescripts test",
>      "eject": "rescripts eject"   },
> ```

3. Install the rescripts plugin for babel:

> npm i @rescripts/rescript-use-babel-config

4. Add this snipper to *package.json*:

> ```
> "rescripts": [
>     [
>         "use-babel-config",
>             {
>                 "presets": [
>                     "react-app",
>                     [
>                         "@babel/preset-typescript",
>                         {
>                             "allowNamespaces": true
>                         }
>                     ]
>                 ]
>             }
>         ]
>     ]
> ```